# A diferença entre a variável de ambiente ClassPath e os arquivos .classpath de projetos em JAR

Tags: java, jvm, jdk, variáveis-de-ambiente

quando instalamos o JDK, nós criamos uma variável de ambiente chamada CLASSPATH, que tem como valor a variável JAVA_HOME, que por sua vez possui o endereço do jdk, que contém todas as bibliotecas para desenvolvimento do Java, correto?

Isso serve para que o compilador Java localize as bibliotecas necessárias para compilar uma aplicação em Java nessa máquina, correto?

**Pergunta 1:** Para executar uma aplicação Java, a JVM também faz busca no ClassPath pelas bibliotecas pra poder fazer a execução? Ou o executável Java já contém toda a informação que a JVM precisa?

**Pergunta 2:** Ao memso tempo, quando criamos um projeto Java, no Eclipse, por exemplo, o eclipse gera dois arquivos dentro do .JAR: o .project e o **.classpath**. Esse **.classpath** é particular de cada projeto Java certo? E ele também tem a função de apontar a localização de recursos (bibliotecas) **para compilação, ou execução ou os 2, não sei**, correto? Mas não basta a existência da variável de ambiente CLASSPATH para o compilador saber onde buscar recursos? Ou cada projeto tem um arquivo **.classpath** porque eu posso ter bibliotecas que não estão no caminho apontado pela variável de ambiente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variável *CLASSPATH*: usado para indicar onde procurar pelas CLASSES do usuário; usado não apenas pela JVM como também por outros comandos do JDK. 
Também existe a opção da linha de comando `-cp` para fornecer o classpath em vez da variável de ambiente.

O classpath pode conter arquivos ZIP ou JAR ou diretórios com os arquivos CLASS (usando a hierarquia dos packages).

Exceção: se usar `java -jar` para rodar um arquivo JAR, a variável CLASSPATH não será usada! Nesse caso o classpath vem do próprio JAR: o MANIFEST.MF pode conter uma entrada Class-Path que servirá para indicar onde encontrar as classes.

Variável *JAVA_HOME*: **não** é usado pelo Java, mas por outras aplicações que usam o Java - já é quase padrão.

**Pergunta 1**: executável pode ser o arquivo CLASS, o JAR ou a JVM (java/java.exe)?!

- CLASS: só contém o *nome* completo (inclusive package) das classes usadas, nada a respeito do caminho.
- JAR: como descrito acima, o MANIFEST.MF possui o classpath.
- JVM: necessita da variável CLASSPATH ou da opção `-cp` ou do MANIFEST.MF no caso de `java -jar` (Java 9 tem a opção de trabalhar com módulos).

**Pergunta 2**: o Eclipse usa o arquivo `.project` para descrever o projeto, `.classpath` para indicar as classes/bibliotecas usadas no projeto. Nenhum dos dois deveria ir no JAR - provavelmente erro de configuração/uso do Eclipse - o usuário normalmente define quais os arquivos/diretórios a serem incluídos no JAR! Mas, por outro lado, esses arquivos não vão influenciar nada no lado do Java, podem até ser útil para 'instalar' o projeto em outro Eclipse/máquina.

Cada Projeto tem o seu próprio `.classpath` para não ter que incluir todas as bibliotecas em todas as compilações e, principalmente, para poder ter versões diferentes de uma biblioteca/classe em projetos diferentes.

Comment: Então esse arquivo .classpath que tem na pasta de cada projeto é somente de uso do Eclipse, certo? Eu abri um para ver e descobri que ele aponta para um "Container" que seria um plugin do eclipse que tem a referência a todas essas bibliotecas. Isso seria para que eu não precise referenciar todas as bibliotecas em todos os .classpath de todos os projetos certo?

Comment: Outra coisa, quando você diz que a variável CLASSPATH é "usado para indicar onde procurar pelas CLASSES do usuário", você se refere às classes do meu projeto ou às bibliotecas Java? Porque eu abri um MANIFEST e o campo "ClassPath" dele só tem um ponto.  Sim, eu to perdido ainda. kkkk